# validate translatable fields with unique rule in dimsav/laravel-translatable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I'm using [dimsav/laravel-translatable](https://github.com/dimsav/laravel-translatable) to make an api translatable.

I have three locale `fa`, `en` and `ar` and there is a `WarehouseType` model like this :

```
class WarehouseType extends Model
{
    use \Dimsav\Translatable\Translatable;

    protected $fillable = ['name'];

    public $translatedAttributes = ['title'];    
}
```

On the other hand I have created a `WarehouseTypeTranslation` like this:

```
class WarehouseTypeTranslation extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['title'];
    public $timestamps = FALSE;
}
```

Now I want to validation incoming requests. for that I wrote a `FormRequest` like this :

```
public function rules()
{
    switch ($this->method()) {
        case 'POST': {
            return [
                'name'    => 'required|unique:warehouse_types',
                '*.title' => 'required|unique:warehouse_type_translations,title',
            ];
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see `title` field must be unique in the database. but I want only `fa[title]` be unique and be check in the DB.

With those codes I have been wrote , I got this error always :

```
{
    "success": false,
    "message": "422 Unprocessable Entity",
    "errors": {
        "name.title": [
            "name.title is required."
        ]
    },
    "status_code": 422
}
```